# Use the reserved variable $$Filepath in dataset paths in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am investigating whether it's possible to use `Copy activity` in bulk and dynamically decide the sink path based on the current file iterated upon?

I know that the `Foreach activity` makes this possible with the use of `@item().name`. However, when looping through say, 10 files, each loop kicks off a new `Copy activity`. This means x10 `Copy activities` which is billed a minimum of 1 minute each. Over the course of one month, this can drastically affect the cost depending on the amount of files and triggers.

This information if fetched from Microsoft docs. It says that the variable `$$Filepath` can be used to set an additional column value.

[image]

So if below sink path is possible to set, for my specific requirement, it would be possible to dynamically move files from one folder to another based on their filename.

[image]

The files could look like blow in source:

- ABCXX.csv
- ABCYY.csv
- ABCZZ.csv

And I would like to have below, dynamically without `Foreach`, in sink:

- ABC/XX/ABCXX.csv
- ABC/YY/ABCYY.csv
- ABC/ZZ/ABCZZ.csv

I've tried to set the sink path to `$$Filepath` but it rendered as a string and not the dynamic value it would be evaluated to in an additional column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It says that the variable `$$Filepath` can be used to set an additional column value.

AFAIK, **`$$FILEPATH` is the reserved variable to store the file path as an additional column** and it is only accessible in the Additional column only everywhere else it will work as string.

> it would be possible to dynamically move files from one folder to another based on their filename.

As you want to Iterate and compare the files based on names to fulfill that you cannot create and add dynamic expression with `$$FILEPATH` It will throw error.

To Iterate and compare the files based on names we don't have any other option than **For-each and until loop**. Both are working same.

Comment: Agreed. I've realized though that even though using the `$$Filepath` would've worked, when used in a Copy activity it would still fail as the inferred schema would not be the same across my files. I've set it up a little bit differently now. Thanks for the reply.